# Can't update a custom object in Appcelerator Cloud Service, got an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, rest, post, appcelerator

I'm working on a C# application that connects to the Appcelerator Cloud Service, so far I can make queries and login, but when I tried to update a `Custom Object` I got the following error: `The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized`. This is my code for my POST request:

```
           url = "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/objects/Reservacion/update.json?key=appkey&id=" + idReservacion + "&noDisponibles=" + noDisponibles;
            wrGetUrl = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            wrGetUrl.Method = "POST";
            wrGetUrl.ContentType = "application/json";
            objStream = wrGetUrl.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(); // this is the line where the error is thrown
            reader = new StreamReader(objStream);
```

I have a theory and it involves the login, at the beginning of my application I make a login which return an ok status, but I think I need to somehow let know ACS I logged in already by sending the session id or something  like that when I try to update the `Custom Object`.

**Edit** That is why I tried to add the cookie in the header like this:

```
                url = "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/objects/Reservacion/update.json?key=appkey&id=" + idReservacion + "&noDisponibles=" + noDisponibles;
                wrGetUrl = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                wrGetUrl.Method = "POST";
                wrGetUrl.ContentType = "application/json";
                wrGetUrl.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", "_session_id=" + session + "; path=/; HttpOnly");
                objStream = wrGetUrl.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(); // this is the line where the error is thrown
                reader = new StreamReader(objStream);
```

Where `session` is the session id I got from my successful login. But even though I added this to the headers in my request the error `The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized`.

**Edit:**
I tried something else:

```
                url = "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/objects/Reservacion/update.json?key=appkey&id=" + idReservacion + "&noDisponibles=" + noDisponibles;
                wrGetUrl = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                wrGetUrl.Method = "POST";
                wrGetUrl.ContentType = "application/json";
                wrGetUrl.Headers.Add("Cookie", session); //changed the header but it didn't work
                objStream = wrGetUrl.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(); // still throws the same error
                reader = new StreamReader(objStream);
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I suspect many C# programmers will think 'ACS' stands for Access Control Service. You may want to spell it out in your title at least to get more answers.

Comment: You're right, thanks for that piece of advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:

```
                String fields = "fields={\"noDisponibles\":" + noDisponibles +"}";

                String url = "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/objects/Reservacion/update.json?key=appkey&id=" + idReservacion + "&_session_id="+session; 
                HttpWebRequest wrGetUrl = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                wrGetUrl.Method = "PUT";
                wrGetUrl.ContentLength = fields.Length;
                wrGetUrl.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                Stream dataStream = wrGetUrl.GetRequestStream();
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fields);
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();


                Stream objStream = wrGetUrl.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(objStream);
```

I had to write in the DataStream of my HttpWebRequest to send the fields I wanted to update. Hope this may help people in the future.